# nagios check_http You must specify a server address or host name

Tags: plugins, nagios

I was not specifying the -H or -I options and was working.  All of a sudden its now asking to specify.  I just need to verify that a url is up and running.

define command{
    command_name    check_https
    command_line    $USER1$/check_http -S -u $ARG1$

Answer (score 0):

I would still HIGHLY recommend putting in an IP or hostname that resolves properly.  I am also assuming your test was on the local machine itself, which will work, but only for the "localhost."  Some patch update comes along, and if you don't have details like hostname or IP, you will be in the position you're seeing now.